# Game theory problem with assymetric information

Tags: game-theory

Suppose you have two players playing a simultaneous game. Player $A$ chooses a move from one of the sets in $S_A = \{s_A^1,\ldots,s_A^n\}$ and player $B$ simultaneously chooses a move from one of the sets in $S_B = \{s_B^1,\ldots,s_B^m\}$. The payoffs for each pair of actions is known to both players. Furthermore, each player can choose from only one set of actions.

Player $A$

- Knows to which set of actions he is restricted
- Knows that player $B$  is restricted to one set of actions
- Does not know to which set of actions player $B$ is restricted

and vice versa.

My question: is it possible to solve this game without assuming some probability function over the sets of actions? Can you give me some articles/info on how to do that?

Comment: I like this question but suspect it's unsolvable in general. Player 1 finds his best overall payoff, realizes Player 2 will know that and respond accordingly, responds to that and so on ad infinitum. As the game progresses, try to divine which moves the other player can't make (ie, if other player makes non-optimal move, presumably because that move is restricted).

Comment: I doubt you can say much at this level of generality, but to get a start you might look at Osborne and Rubinstein's A Course in Game Theory. Chapter 2 talks about Bayesian games, but that involves a prior distribution.  Chapters 11 and 12 talk about games of imperfect information. Also relevant may be chapter 5, because your set-up looks similar to the partitions of information used the in Common Knowledge (or agreeing to disagree) literature.